# Validating Fields of an Object in a Form - Vue 3 + Vee-validate + Yup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, yup, vee-validate

I have a form where certain fields are inside an object:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
    ...
    const schema: yup.SchemaOf<any> =
    yup.object({
      group: yup.string().nullable().required(),
      description: yup.string().nullable().required(),
      user: yup
        .object({
          first_name: yup.string().required(),
          last_name: yup.string().required(),
        })
        .required(),
    })
    const { errors, handleSubmit, isSubmitting } = useForm({
      validationSchema: schema,
      initialValues: {
        group: '',
        description: '',
        user: {}
      },
    });
    const { value: group } = useField<string>('group');
    const { value: description } = useField<string>('description');
    const { value: user } = useField<any>('user');
    const isValid = useIsFormValid();
    ...
</script>


<template>
  <div>
    <label for="group">Group:</label
    ><input id="group" v-model="group" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="description">Description:</label
    ><input id="description" v-model="description" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="first-name">First name</label
    ><input id="first-name" v-model="user.first_name" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="last-name">Last name</label
    ><input id="last-name" v-model="user.last_name" type="text" />
  </div>
  <button :disabled="!isValid">Save</button>
...
</template>
```

But the data validation of this object is only done after changing a field outside of it, i.e. fill in `group`, `description`, `first_name`, `last_name` (in this same order) and the form will NOT be considered valid, only if you edit `group` or `description` again.

How can I make the validation be done when I change the field myself?

Here is the link to [the complete code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9ipghy?file=package.json,src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev).

I am using the following versions:

```
"vue":"^3.2.37",
"vee-validate": "^4.5.11",
"yup": "^0.32.11"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use useField() with an Object, the nested properties lose their reactivity connection. So here are two options to resolve this: wrap useField with reactive() or use useField() for each nested property separately.

option 1

```js
const { value: user } =reactive(useField('user'));
```

option 2

```js
const { value: first_name } = useField('user.first_name');
const { value: last_name } = useField('user.last_name');
```

here is a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-laskev?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: Would it be possible to isolate the two fields in one component by just passing v-model="user" or would I have to pass the two fields separately?